# How to display text to the right of icon in same line

Tags: css

I want to display text on the right side which is aligned perfectly in the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ykdnB/). How can I do it? I do not want to use position absolute.

```
.down {
margin-top: 5px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.icontext {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: The text is already aligned on the right. What do you mean?

Comment: It's already fine? Just a note though, in your Fiddle, you've given both the up and down divs the class of `up`. Shouldn't the second one be `down`?

Comment: Yes it is on aligned but if you see closely then you will find that text is not aligned centered in a row to the icon. Does this help? And yes it should be down.

Comment: Hi @x4ph4r i think u wantto this  http://jsfiddle.net/ykdnB/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will vertically align the `span` tags with the `img` tags

```
.icontext {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.icon{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ykdnB/2/

Comment: It is still not exactly what I want. Both icons seems to be like one is a little down and second one is a little up.

Comment: That may be due to the images.  I think there is whitespace on the top and bottom of them that creates that illusion.  If you look at it with firebug layout they are perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `float:left;` on the icon

Answer (score 1):

If you mean vertical-alignment you need to specify a line height for `icontext`. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ykdnB/3/